# Widevine Session Update endless Loop

Tags: c++, widevine

I am using `libwidevinecdm.so` from chrome to handle DRM protected data. I am currently successfully setting the widevine server certificate I get from the license server. I can also create a session with the pssh box of the media im trying to decode. So far everything is successful (all promises resolve fine).

(session is created like this: `_cdm->CreateSessionAndGenerateRequest(promise_id, cdm::SessionType::kTemporary, cdm::InitDataType::kCenc, pssh_box.data(), static_cast<uint32_t>(pssh_box.size()));`)

I am then getting a session message of type `kLicenseRequest` which I am forwarding to the respective license server. The license server responds with a valid response and the same amount of data as I can see in the browser when using Chrome. I am then passing this to my session like this:

```cpp
        _cdm->UpdateSession(promise_id, session_id.data(), static_cast<uint32_t>(session_id.size()),
                            license_response.data(), static_cast<uint32_t>(license_response.size()));
```

The problem now is that this promise never resolves. It keeps posting the `kLicenseRequest` message over and over again to my session without ever returning. Does this mean my response is wrong? Or is this something else?

Br
Yanick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact, that everything in `CreateSessionAndGenerateRequest` is done synchronous - that means by the time `CreateSessionAndGenerateRequest` returns your promise will always be resolved.

The CDM will emit the `kLicenseRequest` inside `CreateSessionAndGenerateRequest` and it doesn't do so in a "fire & forget" fashion, but the function waits there until you have returned from the `cdm::Host_10::OnSessionMessage`. Since my implementation of `OnSessionMessage` was creating a synchronous HTTP Request to the license server before - also synchronously - calling the `UpdateSession` the entire chain ended up to be blocking.

So ultimately I was calling `UpdateSession` while still being inside `CreateSessionAndGenerateRequest` and I assume the CDM cannot handle this and reacts by creating a new session with the given ID and generating a request again, which of course triggered another `UpdateSession` and so on.

Ultimately the simplest way to break the cycle was to make something asynchronous. I decided to launch a separate thread when receiving `kLicenseRequest`, wait for a few milliseconds to make sure that `CreateSessionAndGenerateRequest` has time to finish (not sure if that is really required) and then issue the request to the license server.

The only change I had to do was adding the surrounding `std::thread`:

```
    void WidevineSession::forward_license_request(const std::vector<uint8_t> &data) {
        std::thread{
                [=]() {
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{100});

                    net::HttpRequest request{"POST", _license_server_url};
                    request.add_header("Authorization", fmt::format("Bearer {}", _access_token))
                            .byte_body(data);

                    const auto response = _client.execute(request);
                    if (response.status_code() != 200) {
                        log->error("Widevine license request not accepted by license server: {} {} ({})", response.status_code(), response.status_text(), utils::bytes_to_utf8(response.body()));
                        throw std::runtime_error{"Error requesting widevine license"};
                    }

                    log->info("Successfully requested widevine license from license server");
                    _adapter->update_session(this, _session_id, response.body());
                }
        }.detach();
    }
```